# Вставить элемент перед другим элементом

Tags: html

Есть код:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>o</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    btn.onclick = function() {
      if (!document.getElementById('img')) {
        var
          image = document.createElement('img');
        image.id = "img";
        image.src = "https://c.wallhere.com/photos/e7/46/landscape_nature-159249.jpg!d";
        document.body.appendChild(image)
      } {
        var dd = document.createElement(
          "br")
      }
    }
  </script>
  <p>Здесь</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы изображение появлялось сверху слова "Здесь".
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я понял задачу так: Если на странице нет картинки, то добавить её, иначе добавить <br>. Решение: https://jsfiddle.net/2cxevt1w/3/

Answer (score 1):

Есть метод [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), он вставляет новый элемент перед тем, который укажете вторым параметром.

**NOTE** 
Нужно понимать, что оба элемента ( и новый, и перед тем, которым вставляем ) должны быть дочерними элементами того элемента, у которого вызывается метод `insertBefore`

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  const targetElement = document.getElementById('paragraph');
  if (!document.getElementById('img')) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.id = "img";
    image.src = "https://c.wallhere.com/photos/e7/46/landscape_nature-159249.jpg!d";
    document.body.insertBefore(image, targetElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>o</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
  <p id='paragraph'>Здесь</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант будет создать пустой div над "Здесь" и в него вставлять картинку.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>o</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    btn.onclick = function() {
      if (!document.getElementById('img')) {
        var
          image = document.createElement('img');
        image.id = "img";
        image.src = "https://c.wallhere.com/photos/e7/46/landscape_nature-159249.jpg!d";
        document.getElementById("imageArea").appendChild(image);
      } {
        var dd = document.createElement(
          "br")
      }
    }
  </script>
  <div id="imageArea"></div>
  <p>Здесь</p>
</body>

</html>
```